# How can I persist attributes such as a List or a Map into a JSONB field?

Tags: java, json, spring, jsonb

My object `Tool` has an attribute `List<String> colors` which should be put in a JSONB field (postgres db). I found similar cases which use `@Type(type=JsonType)`, but I think this comes from Hibernate which I'm not using.

My model :

```
public class Tool implements Persistable<UUID> {
    @Id
    @Column("tool_id")
    private UUID id;
    @Column("tool_name")
    private String name;
    @Column("tool_colors")
    private List<String> colors;
}
```

In my service :

```
    public Mono<Tool> createTool(Tool tool) {
        return toolRepository
               .flatMap(toolRepository::save);
    }
```

In the repository

```
public interface ToolRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Tool, UUID> {
}
```

The error when doing the save() : 
`column "colors" is of type jsonb but expression is of type smallint[]`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: why not store them as comma separated list?

Comment: @NiVeR later I'll try to work with searching in jsonb fields